# Why isn't this running in constant space (and how do I make it so it does)?

Tags: clojure

I'm doing Project Euler to learn Clojure.

The purpose of this function is to calculate the lcm of the set of integers from `1` to `m`.

`(lcm 10)` returns `2520`

This is a rather brute-force way of doing this. In theory, we go through each number from `m` to infinity and return the first number for which all values `1` through `m` divide that number evenly.

If I understand what 'lazy' means correctly (and if I am truly being lazy here), then this should run in constant space. There's no need to hold more than the list of numbers from `1` to `m` and 1 value from the infinite set of numbers that we're looping through.

I am, however, getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` at `m` values greater than 17.

```
 (defn lcm [m]
  (let [xs (range 1 (+ m 1))]
  (first (for [x (iterate inc m) :when 
          (empty? 
              (filter (fn [y] (not (factor-of? y x))) xs))] x))))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code is in fact lazy (also in the sense that it's in no hurry to reach the answer... ;-) -- see below), however it generates piles upon piles upon piles of garbage. Just consider that `(lvm 17)` amounts to asking for over 1.2 million lazy filtering operations on `(range 1 18)`. I can't reproduce your out-of-memory problem, but I'd tentatively conjecture it might be an issue with your memory & GC settings.

Now although I realise that your question is not actually about algorithms, note that the production of all that garbage, the carrying out of all those filtering operations etc. not only utterly destroy the space complexity of this, but the time complexity as well. Why not use an actual LCM algorithm? Like the one exploiting `lcm(X) = gcd(X) / product(X)` for `X` a set of natural numbers. The GCD can be calculated with Euclid's algorithm.

```
(defn gcd
  ([x y]
     (cond (zero? x) y
           (< y x)   (recur y x)
           :else     (recur x (rem y x))))
  ([x y & zs]
     (reduce gcd (gcd x y) zs)))

(defn lcm
  ([x y] (/ (* x y) (gcd x y)))
  ([x y & zs]
     (reduce lcm (lcm x y) zs)))
```

With the above in place, `(apply lcm (range 1 18))` will give you your answer in short order.

Comment: I had actually a Java exception which shut the application down because it detected the CPU as used > 98% for gc activity (with clojure 1.1 on(lcm  17) ) on higher values more garbage was generated than could be collected and I got the heap exception. This is the first time I've come accross this.

Answer (score 4):

I'm getting the same OutOfMemoryError on Clojure 1.1, but not on 1.2.

I imagine it's a bug in 1.1 where `for` holds on to more garbage than necessary.

So I suppose the fix is to upgrade Clojure. Or to use Michal's algorithm for an answer in a fraction of the time.

Comment: Ouch, never thought to check this time round. Apparently I'm beginning to forget 1.2 wasn't actually released yet... So this would be the answer to the actual question -- +1. (Now I'll have some fun tracking down the source of the problem; pre-4f6fda549 locals clearing maybe?)

Answer (score 3):

While I accept that this is acknowledged to be brute force, I shiver at the idea. For the set of consecutive numbers that runs up to 50, the lcm is 3099044504245996706400. Do you really want a loop that tests every number up to that point to identify the lcm of the set?

Other schemes would seem far better. For example, factor each member of the sequence, then simply count the maximum number of occurrences of each prime factor. Or, build a simple prime sieve, that simultaneously factors the set of numbers, while allowing you to count factor multiplicities.

These schemes can be written to be highly efficient. Or you can use brute force. The latter seems silly here.

Answer (score 0):

Michal is correct about the problem.  A sieve will be a little bit faster, since no gcd calculations are needed:

**EDIT**: This code is actually horribly wrong.  I've left it here to remind myself to check my work twice if I have such a hangover.

```
(ns euler (:use clojure.contrib.math))

(defn sieve 
  ([m] (sieve m (vec (repeat (+ 1 m) true)) 2))
  ([m sieve-vector factor] 
       (if (< factor m) 
       (if (sieve-vector factor)
           (recur m 
              (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 false)
                  sieve-vector
                  (range (* 2 factor) (+ 1 m) factor))
              (inc factor))
           (recur m sieve-vector (inc factor)))
       sieve-vector)))

(defn primes [m] (map key (filter val (seq (zipmap (range 2 m) (subvec (sieve m)  2))))))

(defn prime-Powers-LCM [m] (zipmap (primes m) (map #(quot m %) (primes m))))

(defn LCM [m] (reduce #(* %1 (expt (key %2) (val %2))) 1 (seq (prime-Powers-LCM m))))
```

Comment: I should mention that this is overkill for the project euler problem.

Comment: This doesn't return the correct results, though -- `(LCM 10)` returns `151200` (should be `2520`).

Comment: Upon a second look, the reason why the above doesn't work is that `prime-Powers-LCM` doesn't do what I guess it's supposed to do. Here's a working version (which makes `LCM` above return correct results): http://gist.github.com/446158

Comment: Incidentally, which version is faster depends on whether very large ranges might be involved. We've got `(time (apply lcm (range 1 1001)))` (with the `lcm` from my answer) in the ballpark of `(time (LCM 70))` on my machine. Around `(LCM 10000)` the difference is not staggering any more though, and then `LCM` goes on to stay useful for larger inputs, while the step-wise approach of `lcm` breaks down pretty bad. Of course `lcm` can handle sets of numbers which are not ranges; adapting `LCM` to do that could be problematic, I think. All things considered, I suppose both might have their uses.

Comment: @Michał Marczyk: Oh, god yeah, that's horrible.  You're right, there's a fairly bad logical error there.  I'm leaving this up for the time being, per the notice I'm putting in my answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the Gist I posted? (See the link in one of the comments above.) I think it fixes your code (actually just the one function which seems to require a fix).